# In-place Acceptance Problem

Tags: computability, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

> In-place Acceptance Problem (InAP)
> Instance: A deterministic Turing Machine M and a w input for it.
> Question: Does M accept the input w without going through cell (|w|+1)?
> Show that InAP is PSPACE-complete.

I am having problems in finding information about InAP and I have no idea how I can show that it is PSPACE-complete. Any advice or starting point will be really valuable.

Comment: You don't need to use bold for multiple sentences.   If you're quoting someone else, please use a Markdown block quote, which is done by putting `>` at the start of the line.  Where did you encounter this task?  Is that paragraph copied from somewhere else?  We require you to provide proper credit for the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I assume this is homework from a class. (1) Have you seen examples of PSPACE-complete problems in that class? If yes, perhaps you could write a reduction from that PSPACE-complete problem to InAP? (2) Can you notice a similarity between InAP and another well-known problem? For instance, do you know of another problem where the input is a Turing Machine and an input for it? Do you remember the techniques that were used to prove that that other problem was "difficult"? Could you use similar techniques here?